# Trying to download a PDF and set the filename with express

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to use content-disposition to force a download of a PDF and set the filename, which isn't working. In the network panel I'm seeing that the headers have been set correctly yet the PDF is opening in the browser instead of downloading, and the file name is incorrect and is just a random bunch of characters. Is there something I'm missing? I've tried in both chrome and Firefox with the same result where both show the correct headers in the network tab but the PDF only renders in the browser.

```
res.on('end', function() {
  const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  response.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  response.setHeader(
    'Content-Disposition',
    'attachment; filename="Report.pdf"',
  );
  response.send(body);
});
```

[image]

Comment: setHeader is a native method of node.js, if your server is express, try using express set method. or try https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-disposition

Comment: There is also inbuilt res.attachment you can use http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.attachment

Comment: Just tried using set instead of setHeader and got the same result. Headers are still showing up in the network tab correctly but no download or filename.

Comment: I came across res.attachment while researching this but that's for files saved on the servers local file system and not a buffer.

Comment: can you try removing the double quotes from the filename

Comment: No change other than in the network panel it's showing the filename without quotes now, as expected.

Comment: Then try res.download. If that works...

Comment: Well....I created a local text file to test trying res.download....and it opened the txt file in the browser instead. Now I'm really lost.

Comment: Can you try adding the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question so that I can recreate the problem on my side.

Comment: One possibility is also that you're making an AJAX or another asynchronous background call from the client. In this case, headers will not work.

Comment: Yes it's getting a bit late here but I was just reading something similar to what you just said. Our UI is calling a server that is run separately from the UI to get the PDF.